# I have a situation where data-deduplication in Server 2012 has corrupted the metadata - how can I copy these files from an old repository?

Tags: robocopy, deduplication

I have two drives - drive D: and drive F:. Both of these are drives locally attached to the Server 2012 machine. drive F is a legacy store of data migrating to a new drive (D) as it's larger.

Data Deduplication was enabled on drive D, prior to a syncronisation of the files from F to D.

Robocopy /MIR has corrupted the deduplication store on drive F, requiring me to re-sync files from the old D drive. (specifically, any that have the APL attribute (Archive, ReparsePoint,SparseFile) on them).

The issue I have is that some of the files on F have been written to since the cutover - I have tried writing a script to locate these files and copy them over, but I would like a better way to go about it!

Currently I have a script that searches for files with the 'ReparsePoint' attribute and writes that to a text file

```
function Recurse($path) {

  $fc = new-object -com scripting.filesystemobject
  $folder = $fc.getfolder($path)

  foreach ($i in $folder.files) { $i | select Path }

  foreach ($i in $folder.subfolders) {
    $i | select Path        
    if ( (get-item $i.path).Attributes.ToString().Contains("ReparsePoint") -
eq $false) {        
        Recurse($i.path)
    }
  }
}

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$outputlist = Recurse($scriptPath) | Out-File -Filepath .\filelist.txt
```

I would then copy from the source repository based on that list. I would, ideally, like it to be a single script!

Any scripting gurus want to help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The below works quite well;

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | 
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" } |
Foreach-Object {
    $currentFileName = $_.FullName
    $oldFileName = $currentFileName.replace("D:\", "F:\")
    if (Test-Path $oldFileName) {
        Copy-Item $oldFileName $currentFileName -Force
        Write-Host "Copied $oldFileName to $currentFileName"
    }        
}
```